# Quintiles error

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC    AAPL_Ret   NFLX_Ret   INTC_Ret
0 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       
1 2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000   -0.07     0.25       -0.05     
2 2008-03-31  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    0.15     0.10       0.06  
3 2008-04-30  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    etc
4 2008-05-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

I am trying to organize the returns for each stock (last 3 columns) into quintiles. I want to scale this (many stocks eventually, not just 3) so I tried this code that would apply the qcut to only the columns in my df that have _Ret in them:

df['Quintile'] = pd.qcut(df[[col for col in df.columns if "_Ret" in col]], 5, labels=np.arange(5, 0, -1))

Error I get is "input array must be 1 dimensional"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `pd.qcut` function accepts 1d array and you are passing a data frame. Instead, you can do something like:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if '_Ret' in col:
        df[col+'_quantile'] = pd.qcut(df[col], 5, labels=list(range(5,0,-1)))
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!