# Relative Quintiles

Tags: python, pandas

My `df`:

```
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC    AAPL_Ret   NFLX_Ret   INTC_Ret
0 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000       
1 2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000   -0.07     0.25       -0.05     
2 2008-03-31  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    0.15     0.10       0.06  
3 2008-04-30  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    etc
4 2008-05-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

I want to calculate quintiles for the stock returns going across the `rows` in my `df`. I thought maybe I can use `pd.qcut` with something like `axis=1` in the formula but the method doesn't take an argument like that. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is unclear for me , also you need a quintiles ? or quantile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031033/quintiles-error

Comment: Hi Wen: for ex, the first line of returns across the row, is -0.07, 0.25 and -0.05. I want to go across from left to right instead of going down the column, to calculate my quintiles. So for that row/date, NFLX would be in quintile 1, INTC in quintile 4 and AAPL in quintile 5

Comment: Wen, yes quantiles

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ".quantile" method :

```
quintiles = df[['AAPL','NFLX','INTC']].quantile(q=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8])
quintiles = quintiles.to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks Konate. I'd like to append to my dataframe. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ok.

So you want this :

```
def QuantScore(x,p,d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

df['AAPL_quartile'] = df['AAPL'].apply(QuantScore, args=('AAPL',quintiles ,))
```

Comment: Where "quintiles" is the dict built in my back comment.

I was inspired by : https://towardsdatascience.com/find-your-best-customers-with-customer-segmentation-in-python-61d602f9eee6

Comment: Thanks again Konate. While I understand the main idea of using apply to run a function on each column, I'm having some trouble following you (beginner). What are the variables, x, p and d and how are you defining them? Also, I want to be able to iterate through all the columns with "_Ret " in them as opposed to individually pick them out in the code

Comment: That's normal, 
I just have 1 pandas year of experience so i can clearly understand ;). 

"apply" allows you to use a function on your column for each row. In our example I specified "df['AAPL']" so the column transformed will be "['AAPL']". 
In our example, "x" will reprecent each row of your column (by using the apply transform). 
"AAPL" refers to the "p" parameter of your function : it refers to the column name. 
"d" refers to the dictionnary "quintiles" you want to use in order to get your quintiles.